# Take set of enums in a constructor and create list - Java

Tags: java, enums

I am wanting to create a new student and instantiate them with a list of subjects that they are signed up for, but am unaware if it is possible or how to accomplish it?

I have initially put an ArrayList in the constructor, but I am certain that this is wrong.

The eventual outcome is that I have a student with Name, ID and an editable list of subjects that they are studying so that they can be added to and taken out of courses as and when...

**Student.java**

```
private String name;
private int id;
private static int counter;
private ArrayList<Subjects> subjects;

public Student(String name, ArrayList<Subjects> subjects) {
    this.name = name;
    this.subjects = subjects;
    counter++;
    id=counter;
}
```

**School.java**

```
  public class School {

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addStudent(String name, ArrayList<Subjects> subjects) {
        Student tempStudent = new Student(name,subjects);
        students.add(tempStudent);
    }
}
```

**Run.java** *where my problems come...*

```
 public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        School school = new School();

        school.addStudent("ABC", Subjects.English.toString().......... );
    }
}
```

**Subjects.java**

```
public enum Subjects {
    Maths,
    English,
    Science
}
```

Comment: try this `school.addStudent("ABC", Arrays.asList(Subjects.English));`

Comment: @xxlali yes, but the arguments should be declared as `List<Subjects>`, not `ArrayList<Subjects>`.

Comment: @MauricePerry yes you are right.

Comment: The error is "Incompatible types. Required ArrayList<Subjects> but 'asList' was inferred to List<T>:
no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to ArrayList<Subjects>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are no creating an `Array` nor adding an `Enum`. Change your `Student` class and every method associated with it to take a `List` and not an `ArrayList` e.g.

```
private List<Subjects> subjects;
```

Then you could use

```
 school.addStudent("ABC", Arrays.asList(Subjects.Maths, Subjects.English));
```

Comment: If you want to later add subjects to the student, this answer is not correct, because the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList(...)` cannot be structurally modified. You should wrap that list either inside the constructor or when passing the argument in a new `ArrayList`, i.e. `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Subjects.English, Subjects.Maths))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
private String name;
private int id;
private static int counter;
private List<Subjects> subjects;

public Student(String name, Collection<Subjects> subjects) {
    this.name = name;
    this.subjects = new ArrayList<>(subjects);
    counter++;
    id=counter;
}

// second constructor for convenience
public Student(String name, Subjects... subjects) {
    this(name, Arrays.asList(subjects));
}
```

...

```
public class School {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addStudent(String name, List<Subjects> subjects) {
        Student tempStudent = new Student(name,subjects);
        students.add(tempStudent);
    }

    public void addStudent(String name, Subjects... subjects) {
        Student tempStudent = new Student(name,subjects);
        students.add(tempStudent);
    }
}
```